# I want to use bootstrap only on the video

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="overlay active">
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DtNAqK_V-lg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I have a lot of other elements in my html file, and I don't want to tha bootstrap rules change them! I just want the bootstrap to the "wrapper" div and its inside. 
But when I paste the link of bootstrap on the  tag, it changes everything.

Is it possible?

Thank you for all help. :))

Answer (score 0):

You can customize Bootstrap by selecting the components to use, see the following link:

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/

but, i do not think there is a component specifically for videos

Answer (score 0):

Go to this link --> [Customize Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/)

Here you can download the css the you want